# TypeScript: How do you test your client-side code?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, amd

When I write tests for my in-browser TS code, I hit the following problem. My "test" code files are located in a separate folder from the "application" code files (an arrangement that I am not willing to give up). Therefore, in order to import my "app" modules, I have to do this:

```
    // tests/TS/SubComponent/Module.Test.ts
    import m = module("../../Web/Scripts/SubComponent/Module");
```

This compiles just fine. But when loaded in browser, it will obviously not work, because from the standpoint of RequireJS running in the browser, the module is located at "*app/SubComponent/Module*" (after being remapped through web server and RequireJS config).

With TS 0.8.3 I was able to pull off [this clever trick](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/934), but in 0.9.0 it no longer works, because now the compiler [doesn't let me treat a module as an interface](http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1101).

**So the question is:** how do *you* test your client-side code?
Clearly, I can't be the only person to be doing it, can I? :-)

Comment: Before I attempt an answer, I'll need a little more information about the frameworks you are using:
1. Are you using `karma` for testing with `REQUIRE_ADAPTER`? 
2. Are you using `grunt` for building the typescript files?

Comment: Yes, I'm using karma, but no, I don't use REQUIRE_ADAPTER. For building typescript I'm using two options: typescript Visual Studio plugin with compile on save and typescript command line compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's ultimately what I've done: it turns out that Karma can handle/watch/serve files that are not within the base directory, and it makes them look to the browser in the form of "**/absolute/C:/dir/folder/blah/file.js**". This happens whenever **files -> pattern** starts with "**../**".

This feature can be used to make RequireJS see the whole directory structure exactly as it exists on the file system, thus allowing the tests to import app modules in the form of "**../../Web/App/Module.ts**".

```
files = [
  // App files:
  { pattern: '../../Web/App/**/*', watched: true, served: true, included: false },

  // Test files:
  { pattern: '../js/test/**/*.js', watched: true, served: true, included: false }
];
```

Reference (version 0.8): http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/files.html

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell if you are using Visual Studio - this next bit is Visual Studio specific...

This is how I do it:

> In my test project, I created a folder named "ReferencedScripts" and
>   referenced the scripts from the project being tested (add existing
>   item > add as link). Set the file to copy to the output folder.

Source: [Include JavaScript and TypeScript tests in Visual Studio](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201302/Blog/Include-JavaScript-And-TypeScript-Tests-In-Visual-Studio/).

Using add-as-link makes the scripts available in your test project.

Not using Visual Studio? I recommend creating a task / job / batch file to copy the files into the test folder. You could even use `tsc` to do this task for you.

Comment: I don't understand how this is supposed to help. TypeScript compiler doesn't care about files added to the project "as a link", it only cares about how they are located on the file system. And I cannot copy the files into the test folder after the fact, because then I won't have intellisense and compile-on-save while writing the tests.

Comment: +1. @FyodorSoikin I think this should help, because typescript will think files are located in the same project as tests. And in reality, they are just "ghosts" of the real files. Have you tried this at least?

Comment: @tengiz, yes, I did try this, and TypeScript doesn't care whether files are in the project or not, it only looks on the file system.

Comment: You may have missed the note in the article: `Set the file to copy to the output folder`. This will ensure the script makes it to a local non-relative path. The following is taken from TypeScript Succinctly: `...Select all of them and change their properties to set Copy To Output Directory to Copy always. This will cause the script files to be placed in the bin directory of the test project when it is built. When you are running under a build system this is required because it may build your projects in a special directory structure, and relative paths would be broken.`

Comment: @SteveFenton, copying application files on build will prevent intellisense from working while writing the test, as well as compile-on-save functionality.

Comment: It sounds like you want something that doesn't exist in real life and you're getting annoyed at everyone supplying answers because no one has the golden bullet.

Answer (score 1):

I am in the middle of a project where I have to migrate parts of a large javascript project to typescript and this is how I managed to keep the tests running:

1. Use [grunt-typescript task](https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-typescript) to watch and compile all my `.ts` files from the source to a `tmp` folder (with their source-maps). If you only have to deal with typescript files, then you can use the `tsc` in watch mode to do it as well. The latter would be faster, but the former allowed me to simultaneous edit javascript and typescript files with livereload.
2. Include the `.ts` files in `karma.conf` but don't watch them or include them:

   ```
   // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
   files = [
     JASMINE,
     JASMINE_ADAPTER,

     // ...

     // We want the *.js to appear in in the window.__karma__.files list
     { pattern: 'app/**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false, served: true },

     { pattern: 'app/**/*.js', included: false },

     // We do watch the folder where the typescript files are compiled
     { pattern: 'tmp/**/*.js', included: false }, 

     // ...

     // Finally, the test-main file.
     'tests/test-main.js'
   ];
   ```
3. Finally, in the `test-main.js` file, I mangle the names of typescript files and declare them as require modules with the correct paths (to the corresponding `.js` file) in `test-main.js`:

   ```
   var dynPaths = {
         'jquery'               : 'lib/jquery.min',
         'text'                 : 'lib/text'
     };

   var baseUrl = 'base/app/',
       compilePathUrl = '../tmp/';

   Object.keys(window.__karma__.files)
       .forEach(function (file) {
           if ((/\.ts$/).test(file)) {
               // For a typescript file, include compiled file's path
               var fileName = file.match(/(.*)\.ts$/)[1].substr(1),
                   moduleName = fileName.substr(baseUrl.length);
               dynPaths[moduleName] = compilePathUrl +
                                       fileName.substr(baseUrl.length);
           }
       });

   require({
     // Karma serves files from '/base'
     baseUrl: '/' + baseUrl,
     paths: dynPaths,
     shim: { /* ... */ },

     deps: [ /* tests */ ],

     // start test run, once requirejs is done
     callback: function () {
         window.__karma__.start();
     }
   });
   ```

Then as I edit the typescript files, they are compiled and put in the `tmp` folder as javascript files. These trigger `karma`'s auto watch and it reruns the tests. In the tests, the `require` calls resolve correctly since we have explicitly overwritten the paths to the typescript files.

I realise that this is a bit hacky, but I had to jump through similar hoops while trying to include all my tests with `REQUIRE_ADAPTER`. So I assumed that there is no cleaner way of doing it.

Hopefully, if typescript becomes more prevalent, we will see better support for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Since the typescript code is compiled to Javascript you can use all Javascript test frameworks.

I am using Jasmine: https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki

You can write your tests in Typescript with the .d.ts file here: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts

But my client code is rather small and compiled to one output file, so I don't have the module issues that you describe.

Comment: Hm... Did you actually read my question? I have the feeling you're answering something else.

Comment: I did read your question. It says "how do YOU test your client code ?". It's a personal question and I gave a personal answer. This is how I test my client code.

Comment: clearly, the OP is expecting an answer to a question he can't articulate properly.

Answer (score 0):

Might be that I misunderstood your question - can't comment yet...

The runtime of the browser does not need any typescript information. So your test script should import the compiled ts files the same way as any other javascript files they need. Might be that you have to copy them to a subfolder of your test-project before you run your script.

I assume the bigger problem is that you have no interface information. Why do you want to import these informations instead of referencing them? Especially since importing them will also occur in the browser.

The Reference will only take place in the IDE , so it does not matter in which folders the interface-files are located.

```
/// <reference path="../../Web/Scripts/SubComponent/Module/References.ts" />
```